# JMeter: Read CSV file contents into JUnit testcase program using CSV Data Set Config

Tags: csv, junit, jmeter

I want to use data from CSV file mentioned in CSV Data Set Config of JMeter into my JUnit testcase program and pass that data to test method.

I know how to get data from CSV Data Set Config for HTTP Request but couldn't find any help for JUnit Request.

My test method is:

```
public void test() throws IOException{

        try {
            CheckUser(UserId);//I want to get this UserId from CSV file mentioned in CSV Data Set Config of JMeter
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();  
        }
}
```

I am new to JUnit and JMeter. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution using:

`JUnitSampler junitSampler=new JUnitSampler();
 String UserId=junitSampler.getThreadContext().getVariables().get("userId");`

Now my JUnit testcase program is accepting UserId from CSV file mentioned in CSV Data Set Config.

Thanks PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE and Dmitri T for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
 JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().get("varName")
```

see:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getVariables()
- https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html

Comment: I put "userId" in Variable Names of CSV Data Set Config and used method you mentioned above JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().get("userId"), but it is not accepting value of "userId" in my program, its displaying null in my method "test()". Any help on this? Thanks for reply.

Comment: any feedback, if answer is ok you should accept it and upvote

Comment: I found solution using little bit different method. I posted my answer below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for feedback although I am rather sure the solution I provided works. But good you found it, good you contribute it, I will upvote your solution

Comment: Thanks PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE

Answer (score 0):

The answer by PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE is correct and should work.

Make sure that your `userId` variable is set and is not null via i.e. [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

Also remember that JMeter Variables scope is limited to current thread group only, if you want to use values from another thread group you need to convert JMeter Variables to JMeter Properties which have global scope. See Knit One Pearl Two: [How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](http://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) for more details.

You can refer a property as follows:

```
JMeterContextService.getContext().getCurrentSampler().getPropertyAsString("userId")
```

Comment: I found solution using little bit different method. I posted my answer below. Thanks for your help.