# How to parametrize Constructor String label of JUnit sampler in JMeter?

Tags: junit, jmeter

Can anyone tell me how to parametrize Constructor String label of JUnit sampler? I tried doing it using `CSV data set config` but it is just taking the variable name instead of the actual `value.${Data}`.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me in JMeter 2.13.

Are you sure your variable has really a value ? use a DebugSampler before it to check this.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help i had tried this earlier but only the variable reference was getting displayed.but this solution worked in the link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292852/jmeter-read-csv-file-contents-into-junit-testcase-program-using-csv-data-set-co/25357261#25357261

Answer (score 0):

Use checkbox `Create a new instance per sample` in `JUnit Request` sampler.

1. Add `CSV Data Set Config` with Variable Names: `Data`.
2. Add `JUnit Request` with:

   - `Classname` with string constructor, like `woolfel.SubDummyTest`;
   - `Constructor String Label` with CSV variable, e.g. `${Data}`;
   - [v] `Create a new instance per sample` - use checkbox.
3. Run test (and see console for woolfel.SubDummyTest).

It work.

If first row of CSV is `StackOverflow`. You will see text `StackOverflow` in console:

```
protected DummyTestCase(StackOverflow)
public SubDummyTest(StackOverflow)
DummyTestCase#setup(): oneTimeSetUp
SubDummyTest#oneTimeSetUp(): oneTimeSetUp
DummyTestCase#tearDown(): oneTimeSetUp
```

In `apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\junit\test.jar` see `SubDummyTest` with string constructor:

```java
package woolfel;

public class SubDummyTest extends DummyTestCase {

    public SubDummyTest() {
        super();
        System.out.println("public SubDummyTest()");
    }

    public SubDummyTest(String arg0) {
        super(arg0);
        System.out.println("public SubDummyTest("+arg0+")");
    }

    public void oneTimeSetUp() {
        System.out.println("SubDummyTest#oneTimeSetUp(): "+getName());
    }

    public void oneTimeTearDown() {
        System.out.println("SubDummyTest#oneTimeTearDown(): "+getName());
    }
}
```