# JUnit - How do I convert a CSV file to a JUnit File?

Tags: csv, testing, junit, jmeter

I am using JMeter to write results into a CSV file.

I want to know if there is a way to convert the CSV file to a JUnit File.

If there is a way, how do I do it?

**EDIT**: This question is different from [JMeter: Read CSV file contents into JUnit testcase program using CSV Data Set Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292852/jmeter-read-csv-file-contents-into-junit-testcase-program-using-csv-data-set-co) because this question is looking at getting data from the CSV file and using it for a JUnit Request in JMeter.

Whereas I am looking for a solution that takes the results of my test (Output: CSV) and converts it into a JUnit XML Format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292852/jmeter-read-csv-file-contents-into-junit-testcase-program-using-csv-data-set-co

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter: Read CSV file contents into JUnit testcase program using CSV Data Set Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292852/jmeter-read-csv-file-contents-into-junit-testcase-program-using-csv-data-set-co)

Comment: Hi @DhruvSingh my question is different as the question you linked me is looking at getting data from the CSV file and using it for a JUnit Request in JMeter.

Whereas I am looking for a solution that takes the results of my test (Output: CSV) and converts it into a JUnit XML Format.

Comment: Hi @StefanBirkner, please refer to my edit or the comment. My question is different from the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any existing converters, there is a [XSLT file](https://gist.github.com/beradrian/9933070a26d7c72ce67ee26242ed5a2b) which you could use for the conversion, however the files need to be in XML. If it plays for you you can switch JMeter to XML output format by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

- JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up
- XML output format is more resource intensive so use it with care

---

Another option is running your JMeter tests via [Taurus tool](http://gettaurus.org/). Taurus naturally supports JMeter tests and has [JUnit XML Reporter](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter) module which produces JUnit-compatible report files.